# Android Studio in Kali Linux : Run button does not do anything at all

Tags: java, android

I have a simple to explain yet hard to solve problem. I installed Android Studio today on linux and managed to copy the sdk's I had in Windows so I didnt have to install them again. Everything works perfectly until I try to deploy the app into my cell phone. When I press the run button literally nothing happens. I dont even get an error message and the list of deployable devices does not show up. I have seen other threads that are similar but have NOT worked for me. Every SDK component is up to date. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to use android sdk for windows in Linux .You have to download android sdk for linux from here https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads

Comment: Its not impossible, well at least for componnts like repository. It works fine if I generate an apk and transfer to phone

Comment: any way to help me?/

Comment: @LuisRivera The tools like `adb` and `emulator` are platform specific. I suspect that you are trying to run `adb.exe` on our Linux machine, which just won't work.